# Set max-width on flex children but stop shrinking at hard coded value

Tags: css

if I have a parent with `flex-direction: row` and `flex-wrap: wrap`
and two children:

how can I set a width of each child to be 50% of the parent at larger screen sizes, but stop shrinking at a hard coded value, for example 35rem so then when there is no more space they will wrap into a column?

```
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='child'/>
    <div class='child'/>
</div>
```

Comment: Set the `flex-basis` to `50%` (or `flex: 1 1 50%` so that it can grow and shrink as needed) and the `min-width` to `35rem` on each child (or just `.child`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the min-width css property and set it to 35rem.